# Is there any way to stop pycurl perform() execution?

Tags: python, pycurl

I'm currently working on a simple multi-threaded downloader with pycurl and python, now I can pause the download if I want but that simply eats too much memory and if the process is killed I cannot directly resume it. So I came up with a workaround (not implemented yet) to stop the download, save the byte position (which I can get with the progress function) to a XML file and then continue the downloads from there by specifying said byte position.

Where I'm stuck at is I somehow need to close the connection while perform() is executing, since perform() is blocking I thought I can call close() on it from another thread but that just throws an exception. I cannot seem to find a single thing in either pycurl or libcurl documentation which can help me accomplish what I want.

As to why I'm using pycurl over the simpler requests, I've been using pycurl for basic automation for a while now and am just used to that, if there's no other way here to do what I want with pycurl then I guess requests might be the last resort.

````py
class Downloader:
    def __init__(self, url, parts):
        self.url = url
        self.fileName = re.search(r"(?:[^/][\d\w.]+)+$", self.url, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(0)
        self.parts = parts
        self.pause = False
        self.fileSize = round(self._getSize())
        self.partSize = round(self.fileSize / self.parts)
        self.threads = list()
        self.curlObjs = list()

    # Get file size by only downloading the HEADER and then calling getinfo for the length.
    def _getSize(self):
        curl = pycurl.Curl()
        curl.setopt(curl.URL, self.url)
        curl.setopt(curl.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
        curl.setopt(curl.NOBODY, True)
        curl.perform()
        fileSize = curl.getinfo(curl.CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD)
        curl.close()
        return fileSize

    # Track individual file part download progress.
    def _trackProgress(self, totalDown, currentDown, totalUp, currentUp):
        pass  # TODO
        # if currentDown != 0 and currentDown == totalDown:
            # print(f"Download Completed!\n{currentDown}/{totalDown}")

    # Calculate the part size, execute _downloadRange in separate threads, merge file parts on download completion.
    def download(self):
        partStart = 0
        partEnd = self.partSize

        for part in range(1, self.parts + 1):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self._downloadRange, args=(partStart, partEnd, part))
            self.threads.append(t)
            t.start()
            partStart += self.partSize + 1 if part == 1 else self.partSize
            partEnd += self.partSize

        for t in self.threads:
            t.join()

        self._mergeFiles(self.fileName)

    # Download the specified range and write it to a file part.
    def _downloadRange(self, startRange, endRange, fileNo):
        with open(f"{self.fileName}{fileNo}.part", "wb") as f:
            curl = pycurl.Curl()
            self.curlObjs.append(curl)
            curl = curlObj.curl
            curl.setopt(curl.URL, self.url)
            curl.setopt(curl.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
            curl.setopt(curl.RANGE, f"{startRange}-{endRange}")
            curl.setopt(curl.WRITEDATA, f)
            curl.setopt(curl.NOPROGRESS, False)
            curl.setopt(curl.XFERINFOFUNCTION, self._trackProgress)
            curl.perform()
            curl.close()

    # Merge the file parts into one and delete the parts.
    def _mergeFiles(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "wb") as o:
            for part in range(1, self.parts + 1):
                with open(f"{self.fileName}{part}.part", "rb") as p:
                    o.write(p.read())
                os.remove(f"{self.fileName}{part}.part")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION.html has a provision for aborting execution from the callback.